# Am I suffering "divitis"? (CSS especialist needed)

Tags: css, html

I've read lots of articles that condemn the excessive use of divs. I have a feeling that I might be doing that in the following mark up:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
}

/* header */

#header {
  background: #EEE;
}

#header h1 {
  float: left;
}

#header h2,
#header a,
#header p {
  color: #999;
}

#header h1 a {
  background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 500px;
}

#banner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
}

#lang {
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 0 0 0;
}

#lang li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

#lang li a {
  font-size: 10px;
}


/* intro */

#intro {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
}

#tagline {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  width: 540px;
  /* 560 */
}

#tagline h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

#about {
  float: right;
  width: 380px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="banner">
      <h1><a href="http://widerdesign.co.nr/">wider design</a></h1>
      <ul id="lang">
        <li><a href="index.php">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="es/index.php">Español</a></li>
        <li><a href="tw/index.php">中文(繁體)</a></li>
        <li><a href="cn/index.php">中文(简体)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="intro">
      <div id="tagline">
        <h2>Nulla vitae tortor mauris</h2>
        <p>Pellentesque faucibus est eu tellus varius in susc...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="about">
        <h2>right</h2>
        <p>Pellentesque faucibus est eu tellus varius in susc...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #intro -->
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</div>
<!-- #header -->
```

**Explanation of the use of those divs:**

- **header:** Defines the background color which expands until the end of the window (lies outside of the `div .container`)
- **container:** centers the content (but not the background)
- **banner:** to define the background or border color around `ul#lang` and `h1`
- **intro:** same as above but for `#tagline` and `#about` (otherwise I have to define say padding or margin for tagline and about individually)

**Am I overusing divs? Can this be simplified?**

Comment: Josh - I think he needs it so that the header image doesn't appear in the container area.

Comment: Jano - beware men bearing gifts of wisdom.  You have some very nicely formatted HTML/CSS here.  Anyone who would make you feel guilty for using divs to format your page (even 10-20 divs if necessary) is bearing bad advice.

Comment: It's fine. Pretty representative of what authoring for CSS-based layout looks like today. In a perfect world where we had full independent positioning (with something along the lines of CSS3 grids maybe) you'd be able to drop a few of the wrapper divs, but that's not going to happen for a long time yet.

Comment: Add one more voice to the "You're doing it right" choir. I'm not sure who these people are that are condemning div use, but I'd be thrilled to hear their alternatives. Nested tables with gif spacers? Your HTML is excellent, don't let anyone tell you otherwise.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It looks perfect. This should be taken as an example!

One symptom of "divitis" is when you see a list of `<div>'s` instead of using a `<ul>`.

Comment: Lol... I wrote a thesis, but your answer sums it up perfectly. +1

Comment: I agree - this doesn't look like "divitis" at all.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes you just need containers. And since HTML4 has such a  small number of semantically named tags, <div> are used for those containers. Divitis is using <div> when there's a much better semantic tag.

Answer (score 19):

For the most part your markup is fine. Each site presents slightly different problems. I would argue that your code could be improved by removing `#intro` and just applying the CSS to the two columns.

Depending on the rest of your page, you may be able to do without the `#header` div.

Additionally, you can style `html` AND `body` if needed to help with multiple backgrounds/containers. Just remember that `body` starts acting like a `div` (doesn't extend to the bottom of the browser) as soon as you start applying styles to `html`.

Using `divs` or the new HTML 5 block elements, is all about making semantic sense first, and giving places to hang your CSS second.

Since each of your `div` elements serves a specific purpose where they provide semantic grouping of elements that go together, I would say your code is just fine.

For the record, this is divitis:

```
<div class='image'>
  <div class='shadow'>
    <div class='bottom-shadow'>
       <img src="..." alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You're using `<ul>`s for navigation, and `<h1><h2>` for headings - that's good enough for me. I couldn't think of a more fitting element for any of the `div`s you are using. Would pass my quality check without further ado.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `<p>`, `<h*>` when you need them so it's correct.

What is bad is using div instead of an appropriate element. There isn't such thing here.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone may have a different opinion on this subject, but here's my opinion:

You're **not** over using `<div>`.

**If** you *were* using `<div>` when you *should* be using `<h2>`, `<p>`, etc, then you would certainly be doing it wrong. In other words, if you're bending `<div>` to fit your every purpose, you've got a problem.

Unfortunately, when CSS started to get popular, there were a lot of articles written promoting this practice with titles/themes following a "Use `<div>` instead of `<tagX>`!" pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can start to use the new HTML 5 elements now, with a few JS tricks.

You then get the really useful header, footer, article, aside and menu elements.

Combine that with CSS3's styles for rounded corners, shadows...  divitis may have a cure, but we will have to wait to get full support for that.

Answer (score 2):

This is great markup. Good semantic use of all elements. And beautiful use of comments. (Yes I saw this was already answered and voted correct but I am new and looking for some points, had I been here first, wammo!)

Answer (score 1):

Not overused at all.  It's clean, semantic code with just 2 divs related directly to styling only (don't know if your .container div has styles - I would guess so and that you use them in other places because it's a class).  Semantic code - that's what counts!  I think you did a great job.

Answer (score 0):

There is one change that immediately comes to mind:
If these are really all of your styles, ditch the `.container` div.  Since it has no styles, it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in FF3.5 and IE8. The background color defined for "header" div, in FF3.5 the entire header div has that color. But in IE8, the background color shows only for the banner and the header h2 in intro div.

So the question is should the background color apply to the entire header div or is it meant only for a specific portion?

And for container div, the attribute class has the value "container". This class is not defined in the css.

Comment: Its OK, I'm using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/> so IE8 behaves like IE7.

Answer (score -5):

> Am I overusing divs?

Depends on your needs, but IMHO no.

> Can this be simplified?

Maybe with tables, but tables are typically rigid and unforgiving when using them across multiple browsers.

Comment: Sometimes the rigidity and unforgiveness of tables can be useful, if that rigidity is what you are after.

Comment: Sorry mate, but tables are not the answer unless you are presenting tabular data.

Comment: Tables should absolutely not be used or even referenced in this scenario.